# WPF - Use of Datagrid, ListView, or Listbox when trying to create a multi-select table that binds to a data source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and I am trying to re-create a design like this:

[image]

The features that I'll need are: the ability to multi-select a row (hence the checkboxes on the right), the ability to be able to bind to a data source and load in data. And finally, the ability to include a small icon on certain rows.

After Googling, I discovered ListView, ListBox, and DataGrid controls but it appears that they can all do a little of something but not all that I need. Can anyone guide me as to which would be the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the use of the `DataGrid` for something like this. They are super flexible and easy to work with once you get used to them. I'm assuming you have a bit of understanding on binding within WPF based on your question. Assuming your classes implement `iNotifyPropertyChanged` a `DataGrid` should work solid for you. Example below, you will have to change your bindings based on your class property names.

This example doesn't make use of the built in `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` as it tends to have issues (ie, it requires focus before you can click on it). This will also give you an idea as to how you can implement an icon column. You can multirow select by just holding control and grabbing different rows, or you can make use of check boxes and bind them to a property in your class that you can access later.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Select, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="150" SortMemberPath="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="University"  Binding="{Binding University}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age"  Binding="{Binding Age}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now just bind to it from your code behind.

```xml
dataGrid.ItemsSource = myClass;
```

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!